# Network multithread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, mechanize, python-multithreading

I'm writing a script in Python that will scrape some pages from my web server and put them in a file. I'm using `mechanize.Browser()` module for this particular task.

However, I've found that creating one single instance of `mechanize.Browser()` is rather slow. Is there a way I could relatively painlessly use multihreading/multiprocessing (i.e. issue several GET requests at once)?

Comment: Have you looked at the Python [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) module?

Comment: Isn't threading module only for starting a new CPU thread?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119680/multiple-asynchronous-connections-with-urllib2-or-other-http-library and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139988/multiple-urllib2-connections and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905800/multiprocessing-useless-with-urllib2

Comment: well, if you don't want to use threading as @ObscureRobot suggested, you can try [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: ObscureRobot and imm: I don't want CPU threads. As my post says, I want "[to] issue several GET requests at once" - as in HTTP GET request. 

@phaedrus - thanks, those are an interesting read. Doesn't seem to be very easy to implement, looks like I'd have to rewrite the entire app (over 3000 lines of code)

Comment: @deusdies, we cant know how to help you unless you give us enough context to isolate what is so hard about using multiprocessing with your code.  Sample code illustrating the problem would make this an answerable question

Comment: related: [Problem with multi threaded Python app and socket connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783735/problem-with-multi-threaded-python-app-and-socket-connections)

Comment: have you tried [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) or [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html) to get concurrent network IO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want industrial strength Python web scraping, check out [scrapy](http://www.scrapy.org/). It uses Twisted for async comms and is blindingly fast. Being able to spider through 50 pages per-second isn't an unrealistic expectation.